# How to use List.sort on values returned from a function that contains an async?

Tags: list, sorting, flutter, dart, async-await

I have this code :

```
 widget.items.sort((a, b) {

           await getItemDistance(a, true);
          await getItemDistance(b, false);

          return (itemADistance)
              .compareTo(itemBDistance);
        });
```

I am trying to sort widget.items list based on values returned from getItemDistance. However I get an error with a red squiggly line that says :

> The await expression can only be used in an async function

and when I try to add async to the sort method I get another red squiggly line that says :

> The argument type 'Future Function(Item, Item)' can't be assigned
>   to the parameter type 'int Function(Item, Item)'

How do I solve this dilemma guys ? :)
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

`List.sort` is a synchronous function that expects a synchronous callback; there is no way to use it with an asynchronous callback.  I would recommend transforming your `List` and doing any necessary asynchronous work *first* and *then* synchronously sorting the results.  Doing so also should avoid calling `getItemDistance` (which, by virtue of being asynchronous, is likely to be expensive) on the same item multiple times.  For example, something like:

```dart
final computedDistances = <Item, double>{};
for (final item in widget.items) {
  final distance = await getItemDistance(item, ...);
  computedDistances[item] = distance;
}

widget.items.sort((a, b) => 
  computedDistances[a].compareTo(computedDistances[b])
);
```

(I don't know what the second argument to `getItemDistance` represents; if you can't get around that, you would need to build one `Map` with `getItemDistance(..., true)` results and one with `getItemDistance(..., false)` results<sup>1</sup>.)

As a last resort, you could write your own asynchronous sort function.

---

### Edit #1

This should be a more efficient version since it doesn't wait for each asynchronous operation one-by-one:

```dart
final computedDistances = await Future.wait<double>([
  for (final item in widget.items) getItemDistance(item, ...),
]);

final computedDistancesMap = <Item, double>{
  for (var i = 0; i < widget.items.length; i += 1)
    widget.items[i]: computedDistances[i],
};

widget.items.sort((a, b) => 
  computedDistancesMap[a].compareTo(computedDistancesMap[b])
);
```

### Edit #2

I've added a [`List.sortWithAsyncKey` extension method](https://pub.dev/documentation/dartbag/latest/iterables/SortWithKeyExtension/sortWithAsyncKey.html) to [`package:dartbag`](https://pub.dev/packages/dartbag) that can do this :

```dart
await widget.items.sortWithAsyncKey(
  (element) => getItemDistance(element, ...),
);
```

---

<sup>1</sup> However, if you need to call `getItemDistance(..., true)` for the first argument and `getItemDistance(..., false)` for the second argument, that implies that [your comparison function probably is not self-consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61881992/).

Answer (score -2):

Whenever you are running async code you should add the async keyword like below. this tells dart you intend to run async code.

Async functions return a Future which tells dart that at some point in the future you are expecting itemADistance or an error.

You will want to return a Future of type int since you are expecting to receive an int itemADistance or an error.

```
   Future<int> widget.items.sort((a, b) async {

                   await getItemDistance(a, true);
                  await getItemDistance(b, false);

                  return (itemADistance)
                      .compareTo(itemBDistance);
                });
```

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thank you for the prompt answer. However when I try this code   I get this error : The argument type 'Future Function(Item, Item)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int Function(Item, Item)'

Comment: if you use the return keyword in a future you should tell dart what type you're expecting to receive in the future. if you aren't returning anything just tell it Future<void>

Comment: Still doesn't work. it shows an error : Expecting ;.

Comment: `List.sort` is synchronous and expects a synchronous callback (i.e., a function that returns an `int`, not a `Future<int>`).  It cannot work with an asynchronous callback.