# sort list based on boolean

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to sort a list based on a boolean using `Comparable` in `dart`. I tried the following but was not able to do it.

In the list, all the elements which are `true` should come first rest of the list should remain as it is.

```
class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
  int id;
  String name;
  int price;
  bool isAvailable;

  Item({this.id, this.name, this.price, this.isAvailable = false});

  @override
  int compareTo(Item other) {
    if (isAvailable) {
      return -1;
    }

    return 0;
  }
}

void main() {
  Item item = new Item(id: 1, name: "Item one", price: 1000);
  Item item2 = new Item(id: 2, name: "Item two", price: 2000);
  Item item3 =
      new Item(id: 3, name: "Item three", price: 500, isAvailable: true);

  List<Item> items = [item, item2, item3];

  items.sort();

  items.forEach((Item item) {
    print('${item.id} - ${item.name} - ${item.price}');
  });
}
```

This should print

```
3 - Item three - 500
1 - Item one - 1000
2 - Item two - 2000
```

`3 - Item three - 500` should come first because it is `true` but it is printing

```
1 - Item one - 1000
2 - Item two - 2000
3 - Item three - 500
```

What am I doing wrong?

This code can be run as it is on [Dartpad here](https://dartpad.dev)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[A `compareTo` implementation should be reflexive, anti-symmetric, and transitive](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031023-00/?p=42063).  Violating these properties can give sort results that are not self-consistent.

As written, your `compareTo` claims that two elements are always considered "equal" in sort order if `this.isAvailable` is false.  But what about if `other.isAvailable` is true?

Your sort should work if you implement `compareTo` properly without trying to take shortcuts:

```
  int compareTo(Item other) {
    if (isAvailable == other.isAvailable) {
      return 0;
    } else if (isAvailable) {
      return -1;
    }
    return 1;
  }
```