# How do you sort a list by bool in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

How do you sort a `List` in dart based on a `bool` value, the `compareTo` method doesn't work with `bool`. I want `true` values to appear at the top of the list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sort list based on boolean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61881850/sort-list-based-on-boolean)

Comment: yup this is a better answer for sure

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can define your own compare function for `bool` and pass it to the `sort` method of `List`.

Example with `booleans` as your `bool` `List`:

```
booleans.sort((a, b) {
  if(b) {
    return 1;
  }
  return -1;
});
```

This example tells the `sort` method that `true` elements should be sorted higher than `false` elements.

Comment: I think that this potentially could generate sort results that are not self-consistent.  See the linked question.

Comment: @jamesdlin I kind of see what you mean from the linked question, but what do you mean by self-consistent? Do you know of any potential inputs that would lead to an incorrect output?

Comment: @jamesdlin I don't believe this has the same issues as the OP of the linked question because it doesn't assume equality, it always says one elements is greater than or less than another.

Comment: Hm, you're probably right in this case, but generally I find it hard to reason about comparison function that violate reflexivity.  Better to not take shortcuts and implement it properly.

Answer (score 3):

For `List<bool>`, you need to define a [compare](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html) function:

```
final boollist = <bool>[false, true, true, false];

boollist.sort(
  (a, b) => (a == b ? 0 : (a ? 1 : -1)),
);
```

output:
`[false, false, true, true]`

The reasons for this situation with `bool` in Dart can be read [here](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/g/misc/c/5BxhAJJOyow).

Comment: OP asked that true values be at the top of the list. The sort should be `(a, b) => (a == b ? 0 : (a ? -1 : 1))`

Answer (score -1):

I just got the same issue, I solve it using the .toString() function. So it's sort separating the 0's to the 1's.

In this case I got a list of forms, some are synced and others no.

Here's my code:

```
final forms = state.forms
        ..sort(
          (a, b) => a.synced.toString().compareTo(b.synced.toString()),
        );
```

Hope it works for you.