# Sort a list of object by bool value

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart

By call my service i received a list of object. this is my object schema:

```
class MyCard {
  final String number;
  final String name;
  final String available;
  final bool isOwn;

  const MyCard({
    @required this.number,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.available,
    @required this.isOwn,
  });
}
```

I want to sort my list according isOwn==true.So in order to i use list.sort :

```
myCards.sort((a, b) => a.isOwn - b.isOwn);
```

This syntax is not for dart !! how can i do with flutter?

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html

Comment: This link is about string but how can i do for bool value? @onetwo12

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031301/how-do-you-sort-a-list-by-bool-in-dart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [this answer i got right result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62031301/how-do-you-sort-a-list-by-bool-in-dart) :

You can define you own compare function for bool and pass it to the sort method of List.

Example with booleans as your bool List:

```
booleans.sort((a, b) {
  if(b) {
    return 1;
  }
  return -1;
});
```

This example tells the sort method that true elements should be sorted higher than false elements.

Comment: And can be simplified to: `booleans.sort((a, b) => b ? 1 : -1)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can implement Comparable from MyCard class and override compareTo method as you need and use it.

You can take a look at that example.

https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-sorting-list-with-comparator-and-comparable