# Sort by multiple booleans

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to sort the list by multiple booleans.

The first `ìf` elements are supposed to be on top.

After that should come overClaimed, expired items.

The first if works, but the rest doesn't seem to sort properly.

```dart
  int _sort(Item b, Item a) {
    if (b.claimable && !b.expired && !b.overClaimed) {
      return 1;
    } else if (b.overClaimed) {
      return 0;
    } else if (b.expired) {
      return -1;
    } else {
      return -2;
    }
  }
```

Input:

```
Item(expired: false, overClaimed: false, claimable: true) // should be 1st

Item(expired: false, overClaimed: false, claimable: true) // should be 1st

Item(expired: false, overClaimed: false, claimable: false) //should be last

Item(expired: true, overClaimed: false, claimable: true) // should be second
```

Comment: Can you provide some test-data and an example on how your want these data to be sorted?

Comment: Added input to the question.

Comment: Your `sort` callback completely ignores `a`.  It *must* return a negative value if `a` should precede `b`, 0 if `a` and `b` should be considered equal, and a positive value if `a` should follow `b`.  Consequently, there is no difference between returning `-2` and `-1`, so that's pointless.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61881992/ for a similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As jamesdlin also says, your problem is that your compare method does not compare against `a`. Instead, you have made some method which returns some arbitrary value based on an `Item`.

I have made the following example which seems to sort your list as you want. I am using your method to get the arbitrary value for each `Item` we are comparing and then comparing these two arbitrary values.

```
class Item {
  final String name;
  final bool expired, overClaimed, claimable;
  const Item(
      {required this.name,
      required this.expired,
      required this.overClaimed,
      required this.claimable});

  @override
  String toString() => 'name: ${name.padLeft(6)}, '
      'expired: ${expired.toString().padLeft(5)}, '
      'overClaimed: ${overClaimed.toString().padLeft(5)}, '
      'claimable: $claimable';
}

void main() {
  final list = [
    const Item(
        name: '1st', expired: false, overClaimed: false, claimable: true),
    const Item(
        name: '1st', expired: false, overClaimed: false, claimable: true),
    const Item(
        name: 'last', expired: false, overClaimed: false, claimable: false),
    const Item(
        name: 'second', expired: true, overClaimed: false, claimable: true),
  ];

  list.sort((a, b) => _getItemScore(b).compareTo(_getItemScore(a)));
  list.forEach(print);
  // name:    1st, expired: false, overClaimed: false, claimable: true
  // name:    1st, expired: false, overClaimed: false, claimable: true
  // name: second, expired:  true, overClaimed: false, claimable: true
  // name:   last, expired: false, overClaimed: false, claimable: false
}

int _getItemScore(Item item) {
  if (item.claimable && !item.expired && !item.overClaimed) {
    return 1;
  } else if (item.overClaimed) {
    return 0;
  } else if (item.expired) {
    return -1;
  } else {
    return -2;
  }
}
```